# Create a streambuf from const char*?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I want to make a read-only buffer from raw data I have so that I can call `boost::asio::buffer_copy` several times in a row without worrying about maintaining the right offset and length.

Is the streambuf the right solutions in this case? If it is, how can I create streambuf from const char* raw data without copying it?

Comment: `std::stringstream`?

Comment: ``std::stringstream`` doesn’t seem to meet ``ConstBufferSequence`` constraint. Should I just write a wrapper like ``const_buffers_1``? I’m not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using Boost, you can use Boost.Iostreams.

```
#include <boost/iostreams/device/array.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream_buffer.hpp>

int main()
{
    namespace bio = boost::iostreams;
    const char source[] = "hello world";
    bio::stream_buffer<bio::array_source>  stream_buffer(source, sizeof(source));
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with ``boost::asio::buffer_copy``