# Create a streambuf from const char* WITHOUT boost?

Tags: c++, stl, const-cast, streambuf

Same question as [Create a streambuf from const char*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38208850/create-a-streambuf-from-const-char) except that **I can't use boost**.

I have to implement an function that takes a `const char *` as input parameter, and to do so I have to call an other function that takes a `istream` as input parameter.

Here is a sample of code very simplified:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std ;

void inner_function_I_cant_change ( istream & input ) // the function I must use
    {
    string s ; // dummy implementation
    input >> s ;
    cout << s.size() << " : <" << s << ">" << endl ;
    }

struct externbuf : streambuf // my own streambuf using a char*...
    {
    int    size ;
    bool   done ;
    char * buffer ;

    externbuf ( const char * buffer , int size ) :
        size(size),
        done(false),
        buffer(const_cast<char*>( buffer )) {} // ...that forces me to an ugly const_cast !

    int underflow () 
        {
        if (this->gptr() == this->egptr()) 
            {
            if (done) return std::char_traits<char>::eof() ;
            this->setg( buffer,buffer,buffer+size ) ;
            done = true ;
            }
        return char_traits<char>::to_int_type( *this->gptr()) ;
        }
    };

void API_function_I_must_povide ( const char * data , int size ) // the function I must implement
    {
    externbuf buf( data,size ) ;
    istream   input( &buf ) ;
    inner_function_I_cant_change( input )  ;
    }

int main ()
    {
    API_function_I_must_povide( "bazinga!",8 ) ;
    }
```

This code I works well but I had to do an ugly `const_cast` !
I tried using a `basic_streambuf<const char, char_traits<const char> >` instead of a `streambuf` but I get many errors that I didn't understand well.

Is there a proper way to do it ?
(and, as I said, I can't use *boost*)

Thanks !

Comment: If you must use `const char*` for the input, then you can't avoid the `const_cast` since `streambuf::setg()` simply doesn't accept `const char*`, only `char*`. However, in your code, I would change `buffer` to be `const char*`, and move the `const_cast` to the `setg()` call. That said, you don't really need the `setg()` at all, see [this `char_array_buffer` class](https://artofcode.wordpress.com/2010/12/12/deriving-from-stdstreambuf/), which is a read-only `streambuf` using `const char*` without `setg()` or `const_cast`.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) is all you need. `std::string str(data, size); std::istringstream stream(str); inner_function_I_cant_change(stream);`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks **Remy**, your link to Art Of Code made my day!

So, for those who are interested, here my new code, without *memcpy* and ugly *const_cast*:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std ;

void inner_function_I_cant_change ( istream & input )
    {
    char buffer [1000] ;
    input.read( buffer,sizeof buffer ) ;
    string s1( buffer,input.gcount()) ;
    string s2( "hello \0 world !",15 ) ;
    if (s1 == s2) 
        cout << "success!" ;
    }

struct externbuf : public streambuf 
    {
    externbuf ( const char * data , unsigned int len ) : begin(data),crt(data),end(data + len) {}

    int_type underflow ()
        {
        return crt == end ? traits_type::eof() : traits_type::to_int_type( *crt ) ;
        }
    int_type uflow ()
        {
        return crt == end ? traits_type::eof() : traits_type::to_int_type( *crt++ ) ;
        }
    int_type pbackfail ( int_type ch )
        {
        bool cond = crt == begin || (ch != traits_type::eof() && ch != crt[-1]) ;
        return cond ? traits_type::eof() : traits_type::to_int_type( *--crt ) ;
        }
    streamsize showmanyc ()
        {
        return end - crt ;
        }

    const char *begin,*crt,*end ;
    };

void API_function_I_must_povide ( const char * data , int size )
    {
    externbuf buf( data,size ) ; 
    istream input( &buf ) ;
    inner_function_I_cant_change( input )  ;
    }

int main ()
    {
    API_function_I_must_povide( "hello \0 world !",15 ) ;
    }
```

Thanks **Pete**, your solution is development-less but I'm afraid it induces a *memcpy* from *data* to the inner buffer of the *std::string*. And since my buffer may be very big, I try to avoid them as much as possible.